# Javascript Modules Newbie

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, module

I know I'm behind the times a bit, but I've just come across the javascript module pattern.  I'm re-writing some projects using and was wondering about the efficiency of my below code.  It's a very basic script that updates CSS on certain elements.

```
/*---- CSS Styling Functions ----*/
$(document).ready(function() { cssStyler.init('breadcrumbs');});

$(".toggle_category").click(function(){ cssStyler.init('label');});

var cssStyler = {       

    breadcrumbs: {
        id: $("#category_id").val(),
        id2: $("#art_id").val(),
        attr: "color",
        tag: "#CD661D",
    },

    label: {
        id: "alert_request",
        attr: "display",
        tag: "block",
        tag2: "none"
    },

init: function(config) {

    elems = new Array();
    elems[0] = $('#'+cssStyler[config].id)[0];
    elems[1] = $('#'+cssStyler[config].id2)[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {    
        if(elems[i]){
            if (elems[i].style[cssStyler[config].attr] != cssStyler[config].tag) {
                elems[i].style[cssStyler[config].attr] = cssStyler[config].tag; 
                }
            else {
                elems[i].style[cssStyler[config].attr] = cssStyler[config].tag2;
                }
            }}
    }   
};
```

});

As you can see, it gets elements on the page and changes the CSS.  The breadcrumbs runs on page ready and the label gets hidden/un-hidden upon a click.

My concern, having never really touched modules before, is over efficiency.  Is it ok to have two lots of 'config' and run the function depending on the variable passed to it?  Is there a better way of doing things?

Any recommendations for improvement would be appreciated.  If it's complete garbage then say so, it won't hurt my feelings - i promise.

Comment: Really a question for [codereview.se] 

Comment: Apart from that you forgot [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) and `elems` is unintentionally global, your module code is really fine. Maybe you should name `init` differently, because an init function is usually supposed to be called only once.

Comment: There is a codereview.stackexchange.com ??? Excellent!

Comment: Thanks Mike W, didn't realise there was a code review.  I'll use that.

Thanks also Bergi for the comments, will fix those up cheers!